# how to use document.body

Tags: jquery, html

I want to use .body with a div.
Ex- I have a div - **"mydiv"**
I want to use *("mydiv").body* just like *document.body*
Can anyone help me out here.

Comment: (a shot in the dark) Are you talking about [.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/) method here?

Comment: `document.body` refers to the `<body>` (or similar) tag. A div has no body tag ?

Comment: Please explain on what you are trying to accomplish instead of asking for specifics, it's clear your going about it the wrong way.

Answer (score 1):

`document.body` is a way to get access to the document's `<body>` element.

A `<div>` cannot contain a `<body>` element, so it doesn't make sense to try to get it through one.

You can find the `<body>` element that a `<div>` is inside with [`parents('body')`](http://api.jquery.com/parents/)

You can modify the content of a `<div>` with `jQuery('#myDiv')...` just as you can modify the content of the body with `jQuery(document.body)...`.

---

Update in response to comment:

The document loaded into an `<iframe>` is *a different document*. To access its DOM you have to access the iframe and get the document in the iframe (*then* you can access its body).

```
jQuery('iframe#myIframe').contents().find('body')
```

This *is* subject to [the Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

Comment: "A <div> cannot contain a <body>" Thats true but a div can contains an iframe which can contains a body tag. +1 as a form of apology  :)

Comment: Now your answer is complete :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set the html of mydiv, try:-

```
$('#mydiv').html('your new text');
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please specify what do you want to access of the element `myDiv`?
If you want to access its contents you can use

```
$("#mydiv").html()
```

Answer (score 0):

`document.body` is a pointer to [`<body>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.body) tag in DOM. You can get similar pointer to your div with [`document.getElementById('mydiv')`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.getElementById) or, jquery way, [`$("#mydiv")`](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) (assuming mydiv is an ID of a div). Later you may get/set its inner html ([`document.getElementById('mydiv').innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.innerHTML) or [`$("#mydiv").html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/)) or do something using available methods (like [`element.children`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Element.children)/[`jQuery.children`](http://api.jquery.com/children/), [`element.appendChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.appendChild)/[`jQuery.append`](http://api.jquery.com/append/), [`element.attachEvent`](http://www.javascripter.net/faq/addeventlistenerattachevent.htm)/[`jQuery.bind` or `jQuery.on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/)). Just take a look at available methods and use one you need.

And take a look at some book about JS. Suppose any of a book you may find with simple google request will help you never ask questions like this.